# How to authenticate against an OpenID authorization server in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, openid-connect, openid

I'd like to consume a REST service secured with OpenID from a Flutter client targetting Android, iOS and web.

I found [flutter_appauth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) package, but it seems not compatible with web apps.

Is there any Flutter OpenID package working on all platforms?
I'd be happy with a full web solution (something using system browser and deep links).

Comment: Haven't tried yet (returned to my good old Ionic apps) but this recent plugin seems to be a solution: https://pub.dev/packages/openidconnect